# C# Lambda to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

I'm trying to convert a function in C# to VB.Net 2008 and can't seem to make the Lambda expression work. The code is taken from a [neat little C# SMTP server](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/emailtheinternet-com-sending-and-receiving-email-in-windows-azure) that saves emails to Azure blob storage

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

```
    public void Run()
    {
        var mutex = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        while (true)
        {
            mutex.Reset();
            listener.BeginAcceptSocket((ar) =>
                {
                    mutex.Set();
                    processor.ProcessConnection(listener.EndAcceptSocket(ar));
                }, null);
            mutex.WaitOne();
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?Query=vb.net+lambda+expressions, especially [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it converted correctly for VB 2008 using [InstantVB](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/) from Tangible Software

```
Public Sub Run()
    Dim mutex = New ManualResetEvent(False)
    Do
        mutex.Reset()
        listener.BeginAcceptSocket(Function(ar) AnonymousMethod1(ar, mutex), Nothing)
        mutex.WaitOne()
    Loop
End Sub

Private Function AnonymousMethod1(ByVal ar As Object, ByVal mutex As ManualResetEvent) As Object
    mutex.Set()
    processor.ProcessConnection(listener.EndAcceptSocket(ar))
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The lambda is basically just shorthand for an anonymous delegate.

so replace the

`(ar)=> {//Do Stuff}`

with

```
Sub(ar)
 'Do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: But it's an input parameter on listener.BeginAcceptSocket so it can't be a sub.

Answer (score 0):

I infer you're using Visual Studio 2008 in which case you can't write multiline lambda statements in VS2008.

You'll have to be using VS2010 otherwise you'll have to use [Anthony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464415/c-lambda-to-vb-net/3465014#3465014).